# How to fill the missing values of a column which have both first and last values missing

Tags: pandas, missing-data

I have tried to fill the missing values using bfill/ffill,if i use ffill first row remains missing and if i use bfill last value reamins missing.How can i fill all missing values using bfill/ffill?
Thanks in advance

```
pd.DataFrame([['Eagle River','NaN','light'],
         ['Ybor','Red','oval'],
          ['Holyoke','blue','oval'],
         ['Abilene','NaN','disk']],columns=['City','Colors','Shape'])
```

Comment: Use both, `bfill().ffill()`

Comment: How do you expect to forward fill data that has nothing behind it?

Comment: It really depends on the values you want to fill them with